# Why aren't my objects being converted to strings?

Tags: python

Starting with a python object, I'm getting an error when I try to convert the string to a float using astype(string).astype(float).

I've used regular expressions to remove the units and spaces and removed rows with NA.

```
df['Length'] = df['Length'].astype(str).astype(float)
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-137-724df1c0091a> in <module>
      1 df['Length'] = df['Length'].astype(str).astype(float)
      2 #df['Length'].astype(str).astype(float)
      3 #df['Width'].astype(str).astype(float)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5689             # else, only a single dtype is given
   5690             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 5691                                          **kwargs)
   5692             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5693 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
    529 
    530     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
--> 531         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
    532 
    533     def convert(self, **kwargs):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    393                                             copy=align_copy)
    394 
--> 395             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    396             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    397 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    532     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    533         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 534                             **kwargs)
    535 
    536     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    631 
    632                     # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 633                     values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    634 
    635                 # TODO(extension)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    700     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    701         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 702         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    703 
    704     return arr.view(dtype)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: That last error message suggests the value is a blank string.  Is it?  Also, it _is_ being converted to a string; the error is on the subsequent attempt to convert to a float.

Comment: I'm working on a large datasets and the first 100 values that I see aren't blank strings. How would you recommend testing for and removing blank strings?

Answer (score 0):

As John pointed out the error is on converting string to float. 
To visually check for empty strings use `df['Length'] == ''`. 
To count the number of empty strings use: `sum(df['Length'] == '')`
To drop the rows with empty strings use: `df = df[df['Length'] != '']`. This will modify your whole data frame and not just `df['Length']`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: That works perfectly! I had one row with a blank string and it's now gone and everything works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help! If it solved your problem, you may accept my answer. (Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)